# Duplicated results on Ruby threading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I need to improve a rake task that build cloth looks by fetching the images from external server.

When I try to create multiple threads, the results are duplicated.

But if I put `sleep 0.1` before each `Thread.new`, the code works! Why?

```
new_looks = []
threads = []

for look in looks
  # sleep 0.1 - when I put it, works!
  threads << Thread.new do
    # a external http request is being done here
    new_looks << Look.new(ref: look["look_ref"])
  end
end

puts  'waiting threads to finish...'
threads.each(&:join)

puts  'saving...'
new_looks.sort_by(&:ref).each(&:save)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array is not generally thread safe.  Switch to a thread-safe data structure such as Queue:

```
new_look_queue = Queue.new
threads = looks.map do |look|
  Thread.new do
    new_look_queue.enq Look.new(ref: look["look_ref"])
  end
end

puts  'waiting threads to finish...'
threads.each(&:join)

puts  'saving...'
new_looks = []
while !new_look_queue.empty?
  new_look_queue << queue.deq
end
new_looks.sort_by(&:ref).each(&:save)
```

*Queue#enq* puts a new entry in the queue; *Queue#deq* gets one out, blocking if there isn't one.

If you don't need the `new_looks` saved in order, the code gets simpler:

```
puts 'saving...'
while !new_look_queue.empty?
  new_look_queue.deq.save
end
```

Or, even simpler yet, just do the save inside the thread.

---

If you have a great many looks, the above code will create more threads than is good.  Too many threads cause the requests to take too long to process, and consume excess memory.  In that case, consider create some number of producer threads:

```
NUM_THREADS = 8
```

As before, there's a queue of finished work:

```
new_look_queue = Queue.new
```

But there's now also a queue of work to be done:

```
look_queue = Queue.new
looks.each do |look|
  look_queue.enq look
end
```

Each thread will live until it's out of work, so let's add some "out of work" symbols to the queue, one for each thread:

```
NUM_THREADS.times do {look_queue.enq :done}
```

And now the threads:

```
threads = NUM_THREADS.times.map do
  Thread.new do
    while (look = look_queue.deq) != :done
      new_look_queue.enq Look.new(ref: look["look_ref"])
    end
  end
end
```

Processing the new_look_queue is the same as above.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your code to this one:

```
for look in looks
  threads << Thread.new(look) do |lk|
    new_looks << Look.new(ref: lk["look_ref"])
  end
end
```

This should help you.

**UPD:** Forgot about Thread.new(args)

Comment: Can you explain about the parameters? I can't found documentation for the Thread's constructor.

Comment: I know about Thread.new parameters from some tutorial. I don't know why but there is no documentation about `initialize` method for the Thread class in Ruby 1.9.3, but you can find some pieces of args here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Thread.html#method-c-new